# Packaging and uploading to launchpad is possible from Ubuntu based Linux?

Tags: packaging, launchpad

Is it possible to build packages and uploading them to the launchpad through the Ubuntu based Linux operating systems?

My intention or requirement behind this question is to have a very light Ubuntu based system and have to upload packages from that system, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just going to use a lightweight install of Ubuntu without the desktop packages, then yes, it is possible to create packages and upload to Launchpad. You'd need to have at least `dput` and `build-essential` packages installed in order to be able to build and upload packages. Preferably you'd also need `devscripts`, `ubuntu-dev-tools` and `pbuilder` in addition to build packages.

If you're going to use an Ubuntu-based distribution instead of Ubuntu, like Mint or something, then you need to ensure that the distribution you are using has the required packages (like `dput` for uploading and `build-essential`, `devscripts` and `pbuilder` for building) in order to build and upload packages.

You'll also have to set up dput according to the instructions [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading).

Comment: Thanks , i am on it. could you suggest me a light OS based on Ubuntu on above requirements . it need to consume only 100-250 MB .all this for a old laptop of my amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading a package to a launchpad personal archive is indeed designed to be done from an Ubuntu system (it would be surprising if it required a different platform). Only command-line tools are required which hopefully satisfy the requirements for a lightweight system.

[Packaging/PPA/Uploading](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) explains the process, using the [dput](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/dput) tool.

Comment: yeah i am familier with all those things but i want to know weather it can be done from ubuntu based linux or not because my postitives are they are from Ubuntu so i am thinking like that . thank you.